# Is there a way to copy a 32-bit register into a 64-bit register in arm64?

Tags: assembly, arm64

I am working with arm64 and I am trying to find a way to copy a 32-bit register into a 64-bit register because `mov x1, w6` returns an operand mismatch error because you can't copy a 32-bit register into a 64-bit register with just a simple move instruction.

Comment: I guess you have three possibilities: 1) Sign-extend 2) Zero-extend 3) Just copy the lower half. Which one do you choose?

Comment: What are the advantages and disadvantages of each way and how would I execute them?

Comment: @warcrime Refer to the architecture reference manual.  I think you can just do `mov w1, w6`; writing to a 32 bit register clears the upper 32 bit of the register.

Comment: What kind of data is the 32-bit value?  Might you ever consider that the 32-bit value can hold negative values, like -1?  If so, then use sign extension to preserve negative values in 64 bits.  Consider the data types before deciding, and decide differently for different data types.

Comment: For sign extension you can use `SXTW` (alias for `SBFM`).

Comment: In other words, you have to decide what is supposed to go in the top half of the destination register `x1`.  Zeros?  Copy of the sign bit of `w6` (sign extension)?  The same bits that were there previously?  Or what?  Step back a sec and think about *why* you are doing this - what do you intend to do with the value in `x1` after you get it there?

Comment: @zx485: There is no "just" in copying the lower half. That would mean merging to keep the original high-32 of another register, and you'd have to do that explicitly.  (But yes, turns out AArch64 can do that in a single instruction, unlike x86-64: `bfi  x0, x1, 0, 32` https://godbolt.org/z/YGs3WjWcn.  Also surprisingly to me, the merge result isn't written to a separate destination.  I guess two immediate fields didn't leave room for a non-destructive destination.)

Comment: But speaking of compiler output, have you tried compiling `int64_t foo(int dummy, int32_t x){return x;}` to see what you get?  And the same with `uintX_t`?  https://godbolt.org/z/W54cvsvGf.  As always, ask a compiler how to do the super basics on a new ISA you're learning; it can make examples for you and knows good ways to do things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 32-bit general-purpose registers are really just the 64-bit general purpose registers with the upper 4 bytes zeroed. As commenters have noted, you just need to decide whether you want sign-extension or not.

So if you want `uint64_t x1 = (uint32_t)w6`, you do:

```
mov w1, w6
```

And if you want `int64_t x1 = (int32_t)w6`, you do:

```
sxtw x1, w6
```

Comment: `mov x1, x6` depends on `w6` already being zero-extended into `x6`.  If you're trying to split up a 64-bit value into two halves, or truncate it to 32-bit, you need `mov w1, w6` to zero-extend the low half.

Comment: @PeterCordes True, I was working on the assumption that a previous instruction had used `w6` rather than `x6` as target. I guess there's no reason to ever use `mov x1, x6` in this case...